# set Image from ImageView to Dialog

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog, android-relativelayout

I'm passing a String url from Fragment A to B, and load to `imageView`

```
if (obj?.signature_image?.url != null) {
            Glide.with(activity)
                .load(obj?.signature_image?.url.toString())
                .into(imgSignature)
        }
```

When the `imgSinature` is clicked, a custom dialog will be pop up, and I want to set the image to the dialog. How can I achieve?

```
signDialog = Util().dialogSignature(getActivity())

 imgSignature.setOnClickListener {
            signDialog.show()
            if (obj?.signature_image?.url != null) {
                signDialog.relativeLayout2.addView(obj?.signature_image?.url)
            }
        }
```

**Util**

```
fun dialogSignature(context: Context?):Dialog{

        var dialog = Dialog(context)
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_signature)
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        return dialog

    }
```

**dialog_signature**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                             android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="230dp"
                                             android:orientation="vertical"
                                             android:background="@android:color/white">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:background="@color/colorPrimaryShadow"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                  app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/relativeLayout2" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <TextView
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Place Signature"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"/>

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                  android:id="@+id/doneTxt"
                  android:text="Done"
                  android:textColor="@color/colorDarkBlue"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
                    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout1" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0">
    </RelativeLayout>


    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
              android:textColor="@color/colorDarkBlue"
              android:text="Clear" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
              android:layout_marginStart="8dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
              android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
              android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
              android:id="@+id/clearTxt"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Error in this line  `signDialog.relativeLayout2.addView(obj?.signature_image?.url)`

> Type mismatch. Required: View! Found: String?

Really annoying....

> It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add a url string to a view which is wrong. 
Add an `ImageView` inside your `relativeLayout2` and use `Glide` to load your image url

```
<RelativeLayout 
     android:layout_width="0dp" 
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
     android:background="@color/colorWhite"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout1" 
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" 
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/your_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and in your `onClick`

```
imgSignature.setOnClickListener {
    ...
    Glide.with(activity)
        .load(obj?.signature_image?.url.toString())
        .into(signDialog.your_image)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add an ImageView in `dialog_signautre.xml` and then pass the `signature_image?.url` in a second parameter and set it like this

```
    fun dialogSignature(context: Context?,url:String?):Dialog{

            var dialog = Dialog(context)
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_signature)
val imgSignature = dialog.findViewById<ImageView>(your_imageview_id)//added this line
Glide.with(activity)
                .load(obj?.signature_image?.url.toString())
                .into(imgSignature) //added this line
           dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            return dialog

        }
```